# JQuery Get Parameter Value From String URL

Tags: jquery

I have this jquery :

```
var btn_ongkir_result = $('#ongkir-result').attr('href');
//-- this produce : http://example.com?dest=2313

var current_dest = btn_ongkir_result.param('dest');
//-- I'm expecting 2313 here. but it gives me error on console
//-- btn_ongkir_result.param is not a function
```

how to get `dest` parameter from `btn_ongkir_result` variable? thank you

Comment: If the dest parameter is the only one expected, how about splitting the URL : `var url_parts = btn_ongkir_result.split('dest=');` ? Then, refer to the resulting array, at index 1, this should have isolated the parameter value. I hope this helps !

Comment: Also the [jQuery param()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/) is not doing what you think it does